# Problem with cltk_nlp.analyze() - Wont' read str

Tags: nlp, stanza

I am testing the Classical Language Toolkit "[Demonstration](https://github.com/cltk/cltk/blob/master/notebooks/CLTK%20Demonstration.ipynb)", under the header "Run NLP pipeline with NLP()"

I run it in spyder on python 3.9.18.

I get this problem. It says that the string is "none".
Is it a problem with the Stanza nlp or is it something else?

cltk_doc = cltk_nlp.analyze(text=luke10Tokens)
Traceback (most recent call last):

Cell In[15], line 1
cltk_doc = cltk_nlp.analyze(text=luke10Tokens)

```
doc = a_process.run(doc)

cltk_words = self.stanza_to_cltk_word_type(stanza_doc)

pos: Optional[MorphosyntacticFeature] = from_ud("POS", stanza_word.pos)

values = feature_value.split(",")
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

I hope you can help me further :-)
best regards

I have double-checked the input text and I have checked the CLTK version. I'm stuck so far.

Comment: This is happenkng because stanza v. 1.5.1 is incompatible with the current stanza wrapper that is part of CLTK. Pip install stanza==1.5.0 will do the trick until that problem is fixed.